# Wordpress pagination URL

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, urls, slug

How to get a similar kind of pagination URL in Wordpress?
In both the **URL** you can see **'Faculty'** which you cannot achieve in default Wordpress I guess.

**Listing page:** 
https://engineering.jhu.edu/faculty/?current_page=18#item_list

**Detail page:**
https://engineering.jhu.edu/faculty/xingde-li/

Answer (score -1):

This is not *pagination*, this is *site structure*.

Similar structure can be achieved by the following:

- Pages and subpages (default functionality)
- Posts and categories or tags (default functionality)
- Hierarchical custom post types (using plugins or coding yourself)
- Custom post types and taxonomies (using plugins or coding yourself)

Depending on a variety of causes, possibly, you'll need a plugin or some coding to modify URLs, except for hierarchical pages.

Comment: This answer isn't helpful, please provide detailed code explanation.